# How to construct Sql Server TVP with a non default order of columns?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

My scenario is simple - I create a TVP with an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` as its value and execute the query using it.

The results I get back do not make any sense. So, I wrote a `TraceSql` function that dumps the SQL along with its parameters in a way ready to be copied and pasted into the SSMS.

I was puzzled to discover, that the SQL displayed by my function produces the correct results, when pasted to SSMS and ran there.

Finally, I started Sql Server profiler and found out the source of the mystery.

Here is the SQL produced by my `TraceSql` function:

```
DECLARE @AdmSiteId Int = 93
DECLARE @src dbo.TableOfObjectChecksum2
INSERT INTO @src (Id,Checksum,AuxId) VALUES
 (8395,258295360,1)
,(8395,1114574098,2)
,(8395,-19039848,3)
,(8395,337145572,4)
,(8395,1083939112,5)


SELECT ISNULL(src.Id, dst.ClientId) Id, ISNULL(src.AuxId, dst.ClientLegalId) AuxId,
  CASE
    WHEN src.Checksum IS NULL THEN 0
    WHEN dst.Checksum IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END Checksum
FROM @src src
FULL JOIN AdmCustomerInfoLegal dst ON src.Id = dst.ClientId AND src.AuxId = dst.ClientLegalId
LEFT JOIN AdmClientSite cs ON cs.AdmClientMasterId = dst.ClientId
WHERE (cs.AdmSiteId = @AdmSiteId OR cs.AdmSiteId IS NULL) AND (src.Checksum IS NULL OR dst.Checksum IS NULL OR src.Checksum <> dst.Checksum)
ORDER BY Checksum, Id, AuxId
```

Now here is the SQL as captured by the profiler:

```
declare @p4 dbo.TableOfObjectChecksum2
insert into @p4 values(8395,258295360,1)
insert into @p4 values(8395,1114574098,2)
insert into @p4 values(8395,-19039848,3)
insert into @p4 values(8395,337145572,4)
insert into @p4 values(8395,1083939112,5)

exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT ISNULL(src.Id, dst.ClientId) Id, ISNULL(src.AuxId, dst.ClientLegalId) AuxId, 
  CASE 
    WHEN src.Checksum IS NULL THEN 0
    WHEN dst.Checksum IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 2 
  END Checksum
FROM @src src
FULL JOIN AdmCustomerInfoLegal dst ON src.Id = dst.ClientId AND src.AuxId = dst.ClientLegalId
LEFT JOIN AdmClientSite cs ON cs.AdmClientMasterId = dst.ClientId
WHERE (cs.AdmSiteId = @AdmSiteId OR cs.AdmSiteId IS NULL) AND (src.Checksum IS NULL OR dst.Checksum IS NULL OR src.Checksum <> dst.Checksum)
ORDER BY Checksum, Id, AuxId',N'@AdmSiteId int,@src [dbo].[TableOfObjectChecksum2] READONLY',@AdmSiteId=93,@src=@p4
```

Notice the `INSERT` statements in the SQL captured by the profiler do not specify the column list. However, when I create the TVP I specify a different order of the columns.

Here is the schema of the `dbo.TableOfObjectChecksum2` table UDT:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableOfObjectChecksum2] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuxId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Checksum] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([Id],[AuxId])
)
```

Here is how I create the respective TVP in C#:

```
var items = GetItemsSomehow();
var metadata = new[]
{
  new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int),
  new SqlMetaData("Checksum", SqlDbType.Int),
  new SqlMetaData("AuxId", SqlDbType.Int)
};
new SqlParameter("src", SqlDbType.Structured)
{
  TypeName = "dbo.TableOfObjectChecksum2",
  SqlValue = items.Select(x =>
  {
    var rec = new SqlDataRecord(metadata);
    rec.SetInt32(0, x.ClientId);
    rec.SetInt32(1, x.Checksum);
    rec.SetInt32(2, x.ClientLegalId);
    return rec;
  }),
};
```

I thought that the column order I specified in the metadata array defines the matching between the ordinals and the fields. But it is not.

Now I understand that the best is to change my TVP to pass the columns in the same order as defined in the database. However, out of curiousity, how am I to create a TVP with a different column order, like in my example (which does not work)?

**EDIT**

My English is obviously inadequate to explain myself.

Please, examine the `SqlMetadata[]` argument passed to `SqlDataRecord` constructor. Does the order of the items matter? I thought it does. So, if I pass

```
new[]
{
  new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int),
  new SqlMetaData("Checksum", SqlDbType.Int),
  new SqlMetaData("AuxId", SqlDbType.Int)
};
```

then it means something like this "In the batch insert SQL statement specify the columns in the order Id,Checksum,AuxId". In other words, I thought that the batch insert statement generated by ADO.NET given the aforementioned metadata is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO WhatEver (Id,Checksum,AuxId) VALUES (...),(...),...,(...)
```

I think it is legitimate to have assumed such a logic. Given this assumption the code

```
rec.SetInt32(0, x.ClientId);
rec.SetInt32(1, x.Checksum);
rec.SetInt32(2, x.ClientLegalId);
```

is absolutely valid, because:

- ordinal 0 is Id metadata - given ClientId
- ordinal 1 is Checksum metadata - given Checksum
- ordinal 2 is AuxId metadata - given ClientLegalId

However, what I have stumbled upon is that the order of the metadata items does not matter to ADO.NET internals, because the insert statement actually produced by it is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO WhatEver VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO WhatEver VALUES (...)
...
INSERT INTO WhatEver VALUES (...)
```

Meaning, no matter how I order the metadata items, the actual insert SQL goes by the order of the columns in the database schema. And of course, the code

```
rec.SetInt32(0, x.ClientId);
rec.SetInt32(1, x.Checksum);
rec.SetInt32(2, x.ClientLegalId);
```

becomes invalid, because in the database:

- ordinal 1 corresponds to AuxId and now it is given the Checksum
- ordinal 2 corresponds to Checksum and now it is given the ClientLegalId

So, my assumption is wrong.

Now my question - is it still possible to batch insert using a collection of `SqlDataRecord` objects and have a custom order of the columns? Or pass only the required columns, relying on the defaults and NULLs to kick in? **Because an insert SQL without giving an explicit column list must provide the values for each and every column, even the nullable and default ones**. Otherwise Sql Server spits out *Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.*

Comment: No you cannot.  What is so hard about using the order?  If you have a null you just pass a null.

Comment: What about default values? Suppose I want to omit the columns for which I want the defaults. Can you suggest anything there? What if the default value is `GETDATE()`? You understand that `DateTime.Now` may not be the same thing at all.

Comment: Suppose a lot of stuff.  What have you tried?  It took me 3 iterations of comments for you to even to recognize you did not even have the order right in your code.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have explicitly explained it in the post in the first place. Granted, my English is far from perfect, so let us attribute the confusion to that. Can you be more to the point? The fact that I have to know the default values defined in the database scheme in order to use a collection of `SqlDataRecord` items in a batch insert/update is a nuisance in my opinion. The example with the `GETDATE()` default value demonstrates it. You do not see a problem there?

Comment: It is not my responsibility to explain the behavior of a Microsoft product as I don't work for Microsoft.  Given it took you three iterations to acknowledge inconsistencies in the code you posted I understand it will be difficult for you to deal with it.  P.S. the posted table definition has no defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing this issue and unfortunately there's no way to ignore the order of columns. The only minor improvement I was able to do was strong-typing:

```
 var record = new SqlDataRecord(
        new SqlMetaData(nameof(x.Id), SqlDbType.Int),
        new SqlMetaData(nameof(x.Checksum), SqlDbType.Int),
        new SqlMetaData(x.nameof(x.AuxId), SqlDbType.Int));
    
    var index = record.GetOrdinal(nameof(x.Id));
    record.SetInt32(index, x.Id);
    index = record.GetOrdinal(nameof(x.Checksum));
    record.SetInt32(index, x.Checksum);
    index = record.GetOrdinal(nameof(x.AuxId));
    record.SetInt32(index, x.AuxId);
```

Still the order matters and the name of columns and entities' property name should match.

Answer (score -1):

But the select does not match.
And why inconsistent names?

```
 rec.SetInt32(0, x.ClientId);
 rec.SetInt32(1, x.Checksum);
 rec.SetInt32(2, x.ClientLegalId);


CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableOfObjectChecksum2] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuxId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Checksum] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([Id],[AuxId])
)
```

Comment: `TableOfObjectChecksum2` serves as the checksum holder for any object with composite Id of (int,int). It is a general purpose UDT. In this particular example my object has composite key (ClientId, ClientLegalId). I have another type of objects with the key of (ClientId, ClientContactId). Both can be served by the same UDT. The select **does match** the order of the fields in the `metadata` array passed to the `SqlDataRecord` constructor during the population of the TVP. It is precisely my source of confusion - I thought that matching the metadata is what matters.

Comment: Really?  That is you mapping?  Checksum to AuxId and ClientLegalID to Checksum. If so you really need to work on your naming.

Comment: Of course, not. Look at the `metadata` array - `var metadata = new[]
{
  new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int),
  new SqlMetaData("Checksum", SqlDbType.Int),
  new SqlMetaData("AuxId", SqlDbType.Int)
};` - `Id` is first, then `Checksum` and then `AuxId`. So I thought that this metadata array will be used to generate the column names in that order in the produced query. But it is not, the query produced does not contain column list at all and thus uses the order of the columns as they appear in the database. My question is can I somehow affect the produced query to include the list of columns?

Comment: I am looking - are you?  Really Checksum is supposed to map to AuxID and and ClientLegalId is supposed to [Checksum]?